# How do I change a function with a for loop to a recursive function?

Tags: recursion

I want to change this function into a recursive function, with the same argument.
The original code converts given change (3,99 is 399 here), into a list of tuples of what coins to use to get to this amount.

```
def make_change(amount):
   M=[200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
   W=[]
   for i in range (len(M)):
       m=0
       if amount>=(2*M[i]):
           amount=amount-(2*M[i])
           m+=2
           W.append((M[i],m))
       if amount>=M[i]:
           amount=amount-M[i]
           m+=1
           W.append((M[i],m))
   return W
print make_change(238)
```

Comment: for a recursive function you have to put the `make_change` method call inside of one of the `if` sentences

Comment: The point of the recursivity is to have a control sentence that is going to call the method in case of being required. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: But in this case I would still need to loop over M, right?

Comment: Even in a recursive function

Comment: I'm not understanding. As far as I saw, your code works. What do you need the recursivity for?

Comment: I have a file finder utility, I haven't used recently but the fileFind method applies recursivity: https://github.com/MikeVelazcoMtz/fileFinder/blob/master/fileFinder.py

Comment: It's to practice for a test, I understand recursivity, just don't seem to be able to apply it to this particular question...

Comment: Maybe each case of the if sentences could call the method itself  like this `make_change(amount, W)` and at when amount = 0 `return W`

Comment: The tuples are of the form (value, count), right?

Comment: Yes, the outcome is [(200, 1), (20, 1), (10, 1), (5, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]

Comment: I can only use one argument in the function, only the amount

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your requirements?

```python
def make_change(amount):
    def sub(amount, coins):
        if coins:
            coin = coins[0]
            nb_coins  = amount / coin
            if nb_coins:
                return [(coin, nb_coins)] + sub(amount-coin*nb_coins, coins[1:])
            else:
                return sub(amount-coin*nb_coins, coins[1:])
        else:
            return []
    return sub(amount, [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1])
```

Testing:

```python
>>> print make_change(238) 
[(200, 1), (20, 1), (10, 1), (5, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.